# Extending a monomorphism $K \to E$ to an automorphism of $E$

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Suppose $E$ is a splitting field of a polynomial $f(x)$ over $F$ and $K$ a subfield of $E/F$. Can any monomorphism of $K \to E$ be extended to an automorphism of $E$?

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 11.3 of Stewart, Galois Theory, 4th edition, says that if $L:K$ is a finite normal extension, and $M$ is an intermediate field, and $\tau$ is a $K$-monomorphism $M\to L$, then there is a $K$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ such that $\sigma$ restricted to $M$ is $\tau$.

But Stewart is assuming here that $L$ is a subfield of the complex numbers and so, in particular, separable.

Comment: I get that the K-linearity of $\tau$ is important because of the context, but does the answer to the OP at all depend on whether the base field is fixed under the monomorphism?

Comment: @Quinn, I believe that question is answered at question 341083 (which is the one that has been suggested as an earlier question duplicated by this one).